# anchor target to iframe doesnt work when changed in javascript (opens in new tab)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have some trouble with an anchor tag and iframes...

When i change an iframes name attribute in javascript it does not work for some reason.

Even though it actually was changed(checked it in google chrome developer tools) the url opens in a new tab instead of the iframe. However the old iframes name still works...

here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById('myIframe').name = 'newName';
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" name="oldName"></iframe>
    <a href="https://www.wikipedia.com" target="newName">newName</a>
    <a href="https://www.wikipedia.com" target="oldName">oldName</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

However in stackoverflows built-in fiddle it doesn't open in a new tab (i guess for security reasons?)

On JsFiddle it behaves like it does for me
https://jsfiddle.net/qrxtn3L5/1/

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iframes are created a window will be attached to the iframe which actually is the target. When updating the name attribute of an existing iframe the window inside the iframe doesn’t get updated.

This is not really a bug, but it’s kind of counter-intuitive.

you could fix this with:

```
document.getElementById('#myIframe').documentWindow.name = 'newName';
```

if you remove and recreate the iframe it would work, too.

Also i have to say this: Avoid using iframes all together. It's a bad practice. If your goal is to create a single page application, you might want to consider using a frontend framework like Angular, React or Vue.js (there are a lot more though).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at those frameworks! Which on is the best? what do you recommend?

Comment: To be honest there is no 'best' it's really mostly about personal preferences and in some cases about the use case aswell. I Personally enjoy using Vue.js and React, but it might be different for you.

You might want to check this comparison video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYWYWyX04JI